# Android people app layout

Tags: android

I am workin on an app that needs to display some user contact information such as name, phone number, sms button and home address. I really like the way the People app in Jellybean displays this information in the contact info page. I have looked at the open source code on github but it is very confusing for me to understand. Can anyone please explain how that xml layout is constructed so i may get the same functionality in my app?

Comment: You want to learn XML? Or anything more specific?

Comment: I want to know what xml they use to construct that fragment for detail contact view

Comment: It would be helpful to post a screenshot so we know what you mean

Comment: http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/2011-10-19-13h39_40.png

Comment: @JohnBaum I posted an answer below, too, but: www.androidviews.net/2013/03/tab-carousel-library/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you with the swipable pages and two pictures at the top: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/tab-carousel-library/

The blue labels with an underline are created by adding the following attribute to a TextView: style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#2FC9EC"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/image1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/back"/>        
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>        
    </LinearLayout>    
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">        
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">    
            <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/hori_scroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">       
                        <ImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/image1"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>       
                        <ImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/image1"
                            android:layout_width="250dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
                </LinearLayout>       
            </HorizontalScrollView>   
            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">       
                        <TextView 
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:text="PHONE"
                             android:textSize="20dp"
                             android:textColor="#50A7B3"
                             android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>       
                        <View 
                             android:layout_height="1dp"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:background="#728C93"/>       
               <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_weight="0.60">
                         <TextView 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:text="65656565"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textColor="#696969"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
                      <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MOBILE"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#6D6D6D"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>            
            </LinearLayout>        
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="0.40">
              <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/image1"
               android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>            
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>       
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="EMAIL"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#50A7B3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>       
           <View 
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#728C93"/>
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#696969"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxxxx"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#6D6D6D"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>    
           <TextView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#696969"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
              <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="xxxxxxxxx"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#6D6D6D"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>  
              <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IM"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#50A7B3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
              <View 
                   android:layout_height="1dp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:background="#728C93"/>
              <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#696969"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
              <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="xxxxxxxxx"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#6D6D6D"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
              </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you're posting is (pseudocode)

```
<linearlayout>
  <scrollview>
    <linearlayout>
         <viewpager/>
         <relative or linearlayout>
              <title component/>
              <mobilenumber component/>
              <title component/>
              <listview/> (filled with email component)
              <title component/>
              <listview/> (filled with different components i guess)
         </relative or linearlayout>
     </linearLayout>
  </scrollview>
</linearlayout>
```

I'm assuming you know how to design components

Comment: You cannot have a ListView inside a ScrollView

Comment: Of course you can, you just need to set the height to wrap_content then set the height through code.

Comment: Ah, no, they explicitly state that you should not do that. @JesusS

Answer (score -6):

John, the contacts app is written by the experts at Google, so I wouldn't use that to start learning layout.

If you have web experience, you can consider writing your first version within a WebView.  Many Android apps are written with UIs using HTML.

Otherwise, I'd start with simpler XML. The screenshot you posted is basically a bunch of elements stacked vertically.  Check out  with the orientation="vertical".